# C# Use Constructor in another contructor

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm trying to create a constructor that looks for an object and then uses a different constructor.

I don't want to have two constructors that execute the same code in both and in case of a change I would have to change both.

```
public DokumentHandlowyC(DokumentHandlowy dokumentHandlowy)
{
    Guid = dokumentHandlowy.Guid;
    KontrahentC = new KontrahentC(dokumentHandlowy.Kontrahent);
    Numer = dokumentHandlowy.Numer.ToString();
    Obcy = dokumentHandlowy.Obcy.Numer;
    Date = dokumentHandlowy.Data;
    Pozycje = dokumentHandlowy.Pozycje.Select(x => new PozycjaDokHandlowegoC(x)).ToList();
    KierunekVAT = dokumentHandlowy.Definicja.LiczonaOd;
    Wartosc_Brutto = new CurrencyC(dokumentHandlowy.BruttoCy);
}

public DokumentHandlowyC(Guid guid)
{
    eaContext ea = new eaContext();

    using (var session = ea.Login.CreateSession(true, false))
    {
        var HM = HandelModule.GetInstance(session);
        dokumentHandlowy = null;
        try
        {
            dokumentHandlowy = HM.DokHandlowe[guid];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Enova_BrakWskazanegoObiektu($"DokumentHandlowy o Guid: '{guid.ToString()}'{System.Environment.NewLine}nie istnieje.");
        }

        //How use the contructor with DokumentHandlowy here?

        //Guid = dokumentHandlowy.Guid;
        //KontrahentC = new KontrahentC(dokumentHandlowy.Kontrahent);
        //Numer = dokumentHandlowy.Numer.ToString();
        //Obcy = dokumentHandlowy.Obcy.Numer;
        //Date = dokumentHandlowy.Data;
        //Pozycje = dokumentHandlowy.Pozycje.Select(x => new PozycjaDokHandlowegoC(x)).ToList();
        //KierunekVAT = dokumentHandlowy.Definicja.LiczonaOd;
        //Wartosc_Brutto = new CurrencyC(dokumentHandlowy.BruttoCy);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I don't want to have two constructors that execute the same code in both" Then you should exctract a method with the common code, which is called in both constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `private` method that does the shared functionality (in your example, populating variables) and call the method from both constructors.. see the example below:

```
class Program
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Program(Guid _ProgramId) {
        this.Id = _ProgramId;
        this.PopulateFields();
    }


    public Program(int _ProgramNumber)
    {
        this.PopulateFields();
    }


    private void PopulateFields()
    {
        this.Title = "New Title";
    }
}
```

If you want to call another constructor from another constructor, then you'd need to have the values passed in to the other constructor too in order to call the other constructor when a class is initiated, it is not possible to call the constructor from the body of another constructor..

`public Program(int _ProgramNumber, Guid _ProgramId) : this(_ProgramId) { }`

In the above example, the constructor that takes two parameters, will also call the `Program(Guid _ProgramId)`,

Comment: Och, it's so simple! It will help me for sure. In general, is this possible? This solution will definitely help me at the moment, but I'm just curious.

Comment: @WalczakJakub You can call one ctor from another ctor - but of course within the same class. That´s called constructor-chaining. However you have to do this as very first statement. E.g.:`MyConstructor(int i) : this(i, anotherParam) { ... }`.

Comment: @Adriani6 So, it's impossible if the parameters have to be created inside the body first?  When I invoke a constructor I don't have the others parameters yet. I'm not sure if I'm clear.

Comment: @WalczakJakub Correct, you need to have the values to pass to the other constructor at the time you create the object, i.e. when the first constructor is called. Otherwise a class method is required.

Comment: @Adriani6 Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Would be a surprise if when I call `new DokumentHandlowyC(guid)` and application will execute some database queries or do other "heavy" executions.

If object requires database connection to get all required data for class to work properly, create another class which would do that.

```
public class DokumentHandlowyCFactory
{
    public DokumentHandlowyC Create(Guid id)
    {
        using (var session = new eaContext().Login.CreateSession(true, false))
        {
            var HM = HandelModule.GetInstance(session);
            dokumentHandlowy = null;
            try
            {
                dokumentHandlowy = HM.DokHandlowe[id];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                var message = 
                  $"DokumentHandlowy o Guid: '{id}'{System.Environment.NewLine}nie istnieje.";
                throw new Enova_BrakWskazanegoObiektu(message);
            }

            return DokumentHandlowyC(dokumentHandlowy);
        }
    }
}
```

With such approach `DokumentHandlowyC` keep it's original single responsibility and wouldn't depend on database, and required data can be loaded from web service or file system or from in memory database etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with help from a static method. I prefer this over calling a method from each constructor, which can easily be forgotten or refactored out by someone else.

```cs
public DokumentHandlowyC(DokumentHandlowy dokumentHandlowy)
{
    Guid = dokumentHandlowy.Guid;
    ...
}

public DokumentHandlowyC(Guid guid)
    : this(GetDokumentHandlowyC(guid))
{
}

private static DokumentHandlowy GetDokumentHandlowyC(guid)
{
    eaContext ea = new eaContext();

    using (var session = ea.Login.CreateSession(true, false))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

That said, constructors should do as little as possible, and return fast. Better is to create a factory that does the heavy lifting as described by [fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59069163/11833708).